# How can we get the phone number with Google OAuth API and facebook API used for social login?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, google-oauth

How can we get the phone number with Google OAuth API login.

I am using scopes as

```
'scope' : 'https://mail.google.com  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login '
```

and the request is as

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId': 'me'});
```

Is there any scope we can use to get it.

I am getting response as with no sight of phone number :

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"vPymIyv1bT9LfmoUujkgN2yLMK0\"",
 "gender": "male",
 "emails": [
  {
   "value": "XXX@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ],
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "http://picasaweb.google.com/XXX",
   "type": "otherProfile",
   "label": "Picasa Web Albums"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "4354354334435465",
 "displayName": "XXXXX YYYY",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "XXX",
  "givenName": "YYYYY"
 },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/1100335464643327",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fgsdgfgU9-jU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADkM/fgffdgdkM/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "language": "en",
 "ageRange": {
  "min": 21
 },
 "circledByCount": 59,
 "verified": false
}
```

Comment: You cant Google Oauth API has to do with authentication and has no relation to a phone number.   Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: any idea about Google Data APIs

Comment: Have you tried Googleing it what have you found in your own research can you show us what you have tried please?

Answer (score 10):

if you want to get user phone numbers you have to have authorization from the user: see the following info page : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing

ask the user for this scope of authorization :
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

after you have authorization from user run the folowing request :
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey

the response will be a JSON response formatted as followed:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource

one of the attributes is phone list.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can use google's people API to get the user's phone numbers.
To explore more you can try yourself.
Steps to explore:

1. Visit [this](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) link.
2. Select https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read permission in **People API v1** section
3. Click on Authorize API
4. Choose the account to log in
5. Grant permission
6. Click **Exchange authorization code for tokens**
7. Enter https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/138262720636785143353?personFields=phoneNumbers,emailAddresses link, make sure you **replace the UID**
8. Click on send request to see the response

Comment: When I also asked for the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile permission, I could replace the UID in step 7 with "me" and get a reply, but it didn't include the phone number.

Comment: Hmm, I've used this after adding and verifying a phone number for my profile and I'm not getting the phone number data from the Oauth playground api :(

Comment: @SebastianG The scope description says `Get the phone numbers in user's Google profile`. This most likely means the phone numbers linked to or present on Google plus profile and not the Google Account itself. If you look at responses for other scopes like `birthdays` returns an array of `birthdays` with source type as `Account` and `Profile` respectively. I believe phone numbers don't work that way. [Check this Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661815/cant-read-phone-numbers-from-users-google-profile-using-auth-user-phonenumbe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @SebastianG I just noticed phone numbers are made available if the user adds them in the `Contact Info` section under google personal info (About me) settings. https://myaccount.google.com/profile